# Can you please remove the temporary account's information from my real account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

My account https://stackoverflow.com/users/233286/ilhan has been associated with the "il...@il...name" account. Can you please remove the OpenID "il...@il...name" association from it?

Better, can you please delete my "ilh...@il...name" account? Be careful to keep my "dar...@gmail.com" account.

Comment: You're not supposed to start "temporary accounts" when your real account is suspended.

Comment: You are not supposed to associate two seperate accounts!

Comment: I'm kindly asking from the person who associated the accounts to deassociate them.

Comment: @ilhan, at first I thought you were talking about OpenID association, but apparently your two accounts have been *merged*. That doesn't happen without a reason and, to my knowledge, cannot be undone.

Comment: Then can someone remove il...@il...name email address from my account.

Comment: I wont register the .name domain anymore so i don't want my account to be stealed by the new owner of the .name domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.name` email login on your account has been removed and can no longer be used to access your account.

*Note:* you can do this yourself by logging into your account and selecting **my logins** on your profile page.  From there you can remove any extra logins you no longer wish to have access to your account.

Comment: Thank you for removing the inconvenient association. Note: As I said before there is no "my logins" http://i.imgur.com/3m5tO.png

Comment: @Nick, I suggested the `my logins` tab at first in a deleted comment, but apparently the questioner doesn't see one. Maybe it's due to the account being suspended?

Comment: @ilhan - as noted above, you have to be logged into your own account to see it

Comment: Look at his screenshot. It says his about me is blank. You have to be logged in to see that, right?

Comment: I was logged in. I cannot see "click here to edit" if I'm not logged in, can I?